# How to have more than one plugin in cypress/plugins/index.js file?

Tags: javascript, cypress, knex.js

I have 2 two different functionalities in plugins.

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
const service = require('../../src/services/index');

function getConfigurationByFile(file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve(
    '..',
    'pnb_e2e_tests/cypress/config',
    `${file}.json`
  );

  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile);
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {

  on('task', {
    async getAllPosts() {
      return await service.getAllPosts()
    }
  });

  const file = config.env.fileConfig || 'development';
  return getConfigurationByFile(file);
};
```

As you can see, one of them is for configuration file (development, production and stage) and it's executed when I start project. And the second one is `knex.js` which I use to work with database. When I try to call this function in tests I get an error which says `Please check your plugins file`:

```js
cy.task('getAllPosts').then((config) => {
      console.log('config', config)
    })
```

I, probably, understand the problem, but can't resolve this.

P.S. Knex files:

```js
const knex = require('../knex/knex')

module.exports = {
  async getAllPosts() {
    return knex('posts')
      .select('*')
  }
}
```

And just file with configurations:

```js
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const config = require('./../../knexfile')[environment]
module.exports = require('knex')(config);
```

Comment: What is the knex.js file. Can you share that file?

Comment: This is just query builder, but I can share it

Comment: I may be reading this incorrectly on the error message part. Was `Please check your plugins file:` the entire message shown in the test runner?

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake, this code actually work. It was about envs.